# Does mysql prefer number types or letter types?

Tags: mysql, sql

For a mysql database, is it better to use (for performance etc...) letters or numbers to store data?

**Here's what I mean, 3 examples:** (`125015` represents the `Arts & Entertainment` category)

1. Column `varchar(255)` named
   `category` with a row value `Arts and
   Entertainment`.
2. Column `varchar(255)` named `category_num` with a row value `125015`
3. Column `bigint(255)` named `category_int` with a row value `125015`

So, for a select statement.. Querying from which column would let the server perform best?

```
 1. SELECT from table WHERE
    category = 'Arts and Entertainment'
 2. SELECT from table WHERE
    category_num = '125015'
 3. SELECT from
    table WHERE category_int = 125015
```

Also, would there be any benefits (compared to exaple `1`) for using example `2`, which stores numbers inside a varchar, rather than int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smaller a data type is, the smaller will be an index over it and so faster will be the search.

Numbers clearly rate better than strings. String comparison is known to be very slow.

Example 2 will still be less effective than #3, though possibly somewhat faster than #1 since the string value in #2 is shorter, but anyway #1 and #2 are of the same performance category.

Comment: Also thing about #4 being INT or even MEDIUMINT column type - I highly doubt you will ever need more than 16 million (MEDIUMINT) categories, and if you do, then 4 billion (INT) should be enough.

Comment: ah thanks for the tip.. I forgot about that. I changed it to TINYINT.